# COBOL - EXIT statement weird behavior

Tags: loops, exit, cobol

I came across a strange problem when coding in COBOL.

I coded these perform statements:

```
        PERFORM 000-INITIAL
           THRU 000-INITIAL-EXIT.

        PERFORM 100-MAIN-PROCESS
           THRU 100-MAIN-PROCESS-EXIT
          UNTIL END-OF-FILE.

        PERFORM 900-END-PGM
           THRU 900-END-PGM-EXIT.
```

Then these are the sentences in paragraph 100-MAIN-PROCESS and the next paragraph right after 100-MAIN-PROCESS-EXIT:

```
    100-MAIN-PROCESS.

        MOVE  WS-ACCOUNT-NO         TO  IB-ROUTE-ACCT-NUM.

        CALL IBRTEDBS               USING IB-ROUTE-PARAMETERS.

        MOVE  014                   TO  KEY-DDACCT00-BANK-NO.
        MOVE  'D'                   TO  KEY-DDACCT00-APP-CODE.
        MOVE  WS-ACCOUNT-NO         TO  KEY-DDACCT00-ACCT-NO.

        PERFORM  920-GU-ACCT
           THRU  920-EXIT.

        IF NOT SUCCESSFUL-STATUS
           MOVE 999999              TO SDCR-GENERAL-BRANCH-1
        ELSE
           MOVE DD-ACCT-BRANCH      TO SDCR-GENERAL-BRANCH-1.

        PERFORM 200-WRITE-DATA
           THRU 200-WRITE-DATA-EXIT.

        READ IN-FILE AT END MOVE 'Y' TO SW-EOF.

    100-MAIN-PROCESS-EXIT.
        EXIT.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    200-WRITE-DATA.                               

        INITIALIZE DASDCR-REC.
        MOVE 'L'                    TO  INPUT-LOG-TYPE.
        MOVE 'D'                    TO  INPUT-APP-CODE.
        MOVE 014                    TO  INPUT-BANK-NO.
```

If `END-OF-FILE` is true (`SW-EOF = 'Y'`), the loop should have ended and the process should have continued to paragraph `900-END-PGM`. The problem is, instead of doing so, the process continued to `200-WRITE-DATA`. It is as if it performed `NEXT SENTENCE` after reading the `EXIT` statement. 
Anybody know the reason why it's happening like so? Any solution?

UPDATE:
Corrected sentence `READ IN-FILE`, copied the wrong code. `GO TO 900-END-PGM` was just a temporary fix I used so that the program can run correctly.
I'm also sure about this problem, since I have observed how this run line by line by using debug tool.

And here is the complete code:

```
    PROCEDURE  DIVISION.

        PERFORM 000-INITIAL
           THRU 000-INITIAL-EXIT.

        PERFORM 100-MAIN-PROCESS
           THRU 100-MAIN-PROCESS-EXIT
          UNTIL END-OF-FILE.

        PERFORM 900-END-PGM
           THRU 900-END-PGM-EXIT.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    000-INITIAL.

        ENTRY  'DLITCBL'            USING  PCB-IO-TERM
                                           PCB-DDACCAPR
                                           PCB-DDACCJFC
                                           PCB-DDACCCPR
                                           PCB-DDACCDPR
                                           PCB-DDACCEPR
                                           PCB-DDACCFPR
                                           PCB-DDACCGPR
                                           PCB-DDACCHPR
                                           PCB-DDACCIPR
                                           PCB-DDACCJPR
                                           PCB-DDACCKPR
                                           PCB-DDACCLPR
                                           PCB-DDACCMPR
                                           PCB-DDACCNPR.

        OPEN INPUT IN-FILE
        IF NOT FILE-SUCCESSFUL-STATUS
           DISPLAY 'OPEN INPUT FILE QSAM IN-FILE ERROR: '
           WS-FILE-STATUS
           GO TO 000-INITIAL-EXIT.

        OPEN OUTPUT OUT-FILE
        IF NOT FILE-SUCCESSFUL-STATUS
           DISPLAY 'OPEN INPUT FILE QSAM OUT-FILE ERROR: '
           WS-FILE-STATUS
           GO TO 000-INITIAL-EXIT.

        READ IN-FILE AT END MOVE 'Y' TO SW-EOF.

    000-INITIAL-EXIT.
        EXIT.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    100-MAIN-PROCESS.

        MOVE  IN-DDA                TO  IB-ROUTE-ACCT-NUM.

        CALL IBRTEDBS               USING IB-ROUTE-PARAMETERS.

        MOVE  014                   TO  KEY-DDACCT00-BANK-NO.
        MOVE  'D'                   TO  KEY-DDACCT00-APP-CODE.
        MOVE  IN-DDA                TO  KEY-DDACCT00-ACCT-NO.

        PERFORM  920-GU-ACCT
           THRU  920-EXIT.

        IF NOT SUCCESSFUL-STATUS
           MOVE 999999              TO SDCR-GENERAL-BRANCH-1
        ELSE
           MOVE DD-ACCT-BRANCH      TO SDCR-GENERAL-BRANCH-1.

        PERFORM 200-WRITE-DATA
           THRU 200-WRITE-DATA-EXIT.

        READ IN-FILE AT END MOVE 'Y' TO SW-EOF.

    100-MAIN-PROCESS-EXIT.
        EXIT.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    200-WRITE-DATA.

        INITIALIZE DASDCR-REC.
        MOVE 'L'                    TO  INPUT-LOG-TYPE.
        MOVE 'D'                    TO  INPUT-APP-CODE.
        MOVE 014                    TO  INPUT-BANK-NO.
        MOVE IN-DDA                 TO  INPUT-ACCOUNT-NO.
        MOVE 'B998001P'             TO  INPUT-USER-ID.
        MOVE 624                    TO  SDCR-TRANS-CODE.
        MOVE 650                    TO  SDCR-SOURCE.
        MOVE 0                      TO  SDCR-CONTROL.
        MOVE IN-ORG-BAL             TO  SDCR-AMOUNT.
        MOVE 0                      TO  SDCR-SERIAL-NUMBER.
        MOVE IN-BRANCH              TO  SDCR-BRANCH-NO.
        MOVE '8860'                 TO  SDCR-THP-TXN.

        MOVE 'CBG:'                 TO  WS-GNR-TRLR-1A.
        MOVE IN-BRANCH              TO  WS-GNR-TRLR-1B.
        MOVE 'INV-'                 TO  WS-GNR-TRLR-2A
        MOVE SPACES                 TO  WS-GNR-TRLR-2B.
        MOVE 'DUE-'                 TO  WS-GNR-TRLR-3A.
        MOVE ZEROES                 TO  WS-GNR-TRLR-3B.
        MOVE IN-ACCT-NO             TO  WS-GNR-TRLR-4A.
        MOVE IN-NOTE-NO             TO  WS-GNR-TRLR-4B.
        MOVE WS-GNR-TRLR-1          TO  SDCR-GENERAL-TRLR-1.
        MOVE WS-GNR-TRLR-2          TO  SDCR-GENERAL-TRLR-2.
        MOVE WS-GNR-TRLR-3          TO  SDCR-GENERAL-TRLR-3.
        MOVE WS-GNR-TRLR-4          TO  SDCR-GENERAL-TRLR-4.
        MOVE SPACES                 TO  SDCR-GENERAL-TRLR-5.
        MOVE 'ID'                   TO  CTR1-PREFIX.
        MOVE WSS-CTR-ID             TO  SDCR-GENERAL-TRLR-5.
        MOVE '001'                  TO  SDCR-GENERAL-ID.
        MOVE 'Y'                    TO  SDCR-GENERAL-TTL-IND.
        MOVE 'GNR'                  TO  SDCR-GENERAL-FIX.
        MOVE '0785'                 TO  SDCR-GENERAL-NOBOOK.

        WRITE OUT-REC FROM DASDCR-REC.

        IF NOT ACCT-STATUS-OK
           ADD  1 TO  CTR3
           DISPLAY 'WRITE QSAM FILE LNSDCR02 : '
           DISPLAY 'WRITE/' IN-DDA '/ERROR/ ' STATUS-FILE1.

        ADD  1                      TO  CTR2.

    200-WRITE-DATA-EXIT.
        EXIT.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-ACCT.

        GO  TO  920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCAPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCJFC
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCCPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCDPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCEPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCFPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCGPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCHPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCIPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCJPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCKPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCLPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCMPR
                920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCNPR
        DEPENDING  ON  IB-ROUTE-PROCESS-CTL.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCAPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCAPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCAPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.


        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCJFC.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCJFC
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCJFC          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.


        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCCPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCCPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCCPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.


        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCDPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCDPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCDPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.


        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCEPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCEPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCEPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.


        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCFPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCFPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCFPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.


        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCGPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCGPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCGPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.


        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCHPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCHPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCHPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.

        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCIPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCIPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCIPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.

        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCJPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCJPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCJPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.

        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCKPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCKPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCKPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.

        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCLPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCLPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCLPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.

        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCMPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCMPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCMPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.

        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-DDACCNPR.

        CALL  'CBLTDLI'             USING  GU-FUNC
                                           PCB-DDACCNPR
                                           DDACCT00
                                           SSA-DDACCT00.

        MOVE  STC-DDACCNPR          TO  WS-RETURN-STATUS.

        GO TO 920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    920-GU-DDACCT00-CHECK-STATUS.

        IF DATA-NOT-FOUND
           DISPLAY IN-DDA '---DDACCT ZERO RECORD NOT FOUND...'
           GO TO 920-EXIT.

        IF  NOT  SUCCESSFUL-STATUS
            PERFORM 999-ABEND
               THRU 999-ABEND-EXIT.

    920-EXIT.
        EXIT.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    999-ABEND.

        MOVE  ABEND-MESS(WS-ABEND-SUB)
                                    TO ABEND-TEXT-MESS.
        DISPLAY  ABEND-TEXT.

        CALL  'IBABNDBS'.

    999-ABEND-EXIT.
        EXIT.

   *----------------------------------------------------------------*

    900-END-PGM.

        DISPLAY  'TOTAL READ                  : '  CTR1.
        DISPLAY  'TOTAL WRITE-SUKSES          : '  CTR2.
        DISPLAY  'TOTAL WRITE-FAILED LNSDCR02 : '  CTR3.

        CLOSE IN-FILE
        IF NOT FILE-SUCCESSFUL-STATUS
           DISPLAY 'CLOSE FILE QSAM IN-FILE ERROR: '
           WS-FILE-STATUS.

        CLOSE OUT-FILE
        IF NOT FILE-SUCCESSFUL-STATUS
           DISPLAY 'CLOSE FILE QSAM OUT-FILE ERROR: '
           WS-FILE-STATUS.

        GOBACK.

    900-END-PGM-EXIT.
        EXIT.
```

Comment: I would like to see the code between  `PERFORM 900-END-PGM` and `100-MAIN-PROCESS`. If there is no stop run / goback, the program will simply fall through from `PERFORM 900-END-PGM` to `100-MAIN-PROCESS`

Comment: @BruceMartin I have updated the question with said code

Comment: @AnthonyPangestu - Did you verified in the debugger, that you don't enter the program with the `ENTRY` but with its start in `PROCEDURE DIVISION`?

Comment: @SimonSobisch Now that you mentioned it, the first line in procedure division executed by the program is `OPEN INPUT IN-FILE` instead of `PERFORM 000-INITIAL`

Comment: @AnthonyPangestu Then you have your answer, don't you?

Comment: @SimonSobisch Yeah, the entry statement shouldn't be put in perform paragraph. Have tried so and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of @SimonSobisch, this problem is solved by moving `ENTRY` statement out of `PERFORM 000-INITIAL`, like so:

> ```
>    PROCEDURE  DIVISION.
>
>        ENTRY  'DLITCBL'            USING  PCB-IO-TERM
>                                           PCB-DDACCAPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCJFC
>                                           PCB-DDACCCPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCDPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCEPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCFPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCGPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCHPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCIPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCJPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCKPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCLPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCMPR
>                                           PCB-DDACCNPR.
>
>        PERFORM 000-INITIAL
>           THRU 000-INITIAL-EXIT.
>
>        PERFORM 100-MAIN-PROCESS
>           THRU 100-MAIN-PROCESS-EXIT
>          UNTIL END-OF-FILE.
>
>        PERFORM 900-END-PGM
>           THRU 900-END-PGM-EXIT.
>
>   *----------------------------------------------------------------*
>
>    000-INITIAL.
>
>        OPEN INPUT IN-FILE
>        IF NOT FILE-SUCCESSFUL-STATUS
>           DISPLAY 'OPEN INPUT FILE QSAM IN-FILE ERROR: '
>           WS-FILE-STATUS
>           GO TO 000-INITIAL-EXIT.
>
>        OPEN OUTPUT OUT-FILE
>        IF NOT FILE-SUCCESSFUL-STATUS
>           DISPLAY 'OPEN INPUT FILE QSAM OUT-FILE ERROR: '
>           WS-FILE-STATUS
>           GO TO 000-INITIAL-EXIT.
>
>        READ IN-FILE AT END MOVE 'Y' TO SW-EOF.
>
>    000-INITIAL-EXIT.
>        EXIT.
> ```

Comment: There's still the question while you use an `ENTRY` in general instead of adding the parameters into `PROCEDURE DIVISION USING` directly...

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be the reason (we can't say without the possibility to inspect the code), but your program breaks the program flow because:

```
    READ IN-FILE AT END MOVE 'Y' TO SW-EOF
                        GO TO 900-END-PGM.

100-MAIN-PROCESS-EXIT.
    EXIT.
```

If the file's end is reached you do set `END-OF-FILE` (at least I can assume this, without the code to check, which is likely more clean if you use `SET END-OF-FILE TO TRUE` instead of `MOVE 'Y' TO SW-EOF` btw) and then `GO TO 900-END-PGM.`.
You never reach the paragraph `100-MAIN-PROCESS-EXIT.` and therefore your main loop will still be active.

What does `900-END-PGM` look like? Where is the code placed (is it all "below" your main `PERFORM UNTIL`s?

Additional note: The `EXIT` statement is a no-op, you can replace it with `CONTINUE` to be more clear what it actually does. "EXIT" is just a kind of a comment "somewhere we use `PERFORM THRU` and end here".

Comment: It's not a no-op. It's a conditional return. If the code is under the control of a PERFORM statement, it returns to the PERFORM.

Comment: @EJP I'm quite sure `EXIT PARAGRAPH` and `EXIT SECTION` statements exit the according procedure, `EXIT PROGRAM`, `EXIT FUNCTION`, `EXIT METHOD`, its scope (*similar* to `GOBACK`) but the `EXIT` alone will do nothing. In a `PERFORM THRU` code an `EXIT` anywhere in the middle wouldn't do anything, would it?

Comment: I can only repeat. Under the control of a PERFORM statement, an EXIT statement exits the PERFORM.

Comment: Please lets discuss this in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157569/room-for-simon-sobisch-and-ejp

Comment: @SimonSobisch I have updated the question. I have also tried using `SET END-OF-FILE TO TRUE` instead but it didn't correct the problem :(

Comment: @EJP, that's wrong.  Spec for simple format-1 EXIT.   `An EXIT statement serves only to enable the user to assign a procedure-name to a given point in a procedure division. Such an EXIT statement has no other effect on the compilation or execution.`